# How can i add LIKE query instead of equal in this query statement?

Tags: mysql

I got this error when i add `LIKE` in my query

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' OR agent_ip = 'Counter' OR port = 'Counter' OR 0home_ip_por' at line 45
```

My code is:

```
'.($search_field ?" AND home_id = '$search_field' OR user_id_main = '$search_field' OR home_path = '$search_field' 
                            OR home_name = '$search_field' 
                            OR user_id_main IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `".$this->table_prefix."users` WHERE users_login = '$search_field')
                            OR user_id = '$search_field'
                            OR user_id IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `".$this->table_prefix."users` WHERE users_login = '$search_field')
                            OR agent_ip = '$search_field' OR port = '$search_field'
                            " : '').
```

I need to replace `=` to `LIKE` in this line `OR home_name = '$search_field'`

Comment: can you share the executed query?

Comment: Use prepared statements, otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injection, even if you escape the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'.($search_field ?" AND home_id = '$search_field' OR user_id_main = '$search_field' OR home_path = '$search_field' OR home_name LIKE '%".$search_field."%' OR user_id_main IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `".$this->table_prefix."users` WHERE users_login = '$search_field') OR user_id = '$search_field' OR user_id IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `".$this->table_prefix."users` WHERE users_login = '$search_field') OR agent_ip = '$search_field' OR port = '$search_field'
```

Comment: Yes that work, thanks
& please can you tell me on this `OR home_name = \''.$search_field.'\'` ?